# Negative relative error

Tags: error

I am trying to calculate the relative error between one model and another as follows:

```
(model1 - model2)/ (1 - model2)
```

where `model1` and `model2` are the correct predictions of the models, respectively.
`model1` is better than `model2` and I use this formula to calculate how much `model1` reduces the error. The only thing I am not sure about is how to interpret the results: since `model1` predicts more correct classes than `model2`, my relative error is negative. Let's say I have

```
relative error = -54%
```

how can I interpret the result? Does it mean that `model1` reduces the error by 54%, compared with `model2`?

EDIT:

`model1` and `model2` are the correct predictions of two neural networks on a language task: the neural networks pick the correct word among a limited set of words. `model1`has a better performance than `model2`: therefore the error from this formula will be negative.

Example: given 200 examples, `model1` exactly predicts 150, `model2` only 55. The result should be:

```
(150 - 55)/(1 - 55) = -1.76 (if we calculate the percentage = -175%)
```

Comment: Sorry, don't understand. In what sense are `model1` and `model2` both correct predictions but `model1` better? Even more crucially, what are you using as a measure of error? What is the outcome or response variable? Evidently something with classes, but does that mean binary, nominal, ordinal?

Comment: @NickCox Thank you for your quick reply, I just edited the question, I hope it is more clear!

Comment: I see no obvious point to a relative measure here. Model 1 has 150/200 = 75% correct and model 2 has 55/200 = 27.5%. Why go further? You need to scale by 200; but trying to put the comparison in one number just discards informative detail. The difference is obvious and can be made explicit and the same holds for 3 or more models.

Comment: I can see some point to (`model1` $-$ `model2`) / (`perfect` $-$ `model2`) as measuring improvement in 1 over 2, relative to the maximum improvement possible. (DIsclaimer: I don't work with neural networks or this kind of prediction problem in statistics, so I have no idea what performance measures are standard or common in your literatures.)